# How to change an AWS Serverless application project to just deploy as lambda functions? (No API gateway and cloud formation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, api, aws-lambda, gateway

Originally, we created the project as WebAPI, and were deploying as API Gateway...
Is there a way I could just change the project's deployment to deploy only as a lambda function and not anymore with API gateway and cloud formation?

I am trying not to redo the whole project.

Comment: Take a look at [serverless](https://serverless.com/) framework, which does all these house keeping work nicely. If you have a github project, then please share.

Comment: You must have AWS credentials to access a Lambda.  You'll need to do something to allow that such as AWS Cognito.

Answer (score 0):

Yep just don't add HTTP events to your functions.

```
functions:
  postRoute:
    handler: handler.postRoute
    events:
      -
        http:
          path: /someRoute
          method: post
          cors: true
  anotherRoute:
    handler: handler.anotherRoute
    events:
      -
        http:
          path: '/path'
          method: get
          cors: true
  authorizer:    // NO HTTP ROUTE
    handler: handler.authorizer
    resultTtlInSeconds: 0
  lambdaLogger: // NO HTTP ROUTE
    handler: handler.lambdaLoggerHandler
```

Comment: Ahh hold up I read this as you ARE using serverless, are you using straight cloudformation at the moment?